# TestNG - Test fixture in the style of pytest

Tags: java, testng

Writing Appium tests with TestNG. I'd like to pass the `AppiumDriver` to my test methods as an argument, so I don't have to remember to get it in every test. For example:

```java
class FooTest {
    @BeforeTest
    public void initDriver(){
        AppiumDriver driver = ...
        // do some black magic to add the driver as an argument for all tests in this class
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testLogin(AppiumDriver driver){
        // example
        driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("username").sendKeys("foo");
        driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("password").sendKeys("bar");
        // etc...
    }
}
```

- I can't use a TestNG parameter because they can only be strings.
- I don't want to use a `DataProvider` for this because I want to use them for other stuff
- I don't want to put it in the `ITestContext`, because then I have to remember to get it. (This is what I'm currently doing)
- I can't put it as a class property, because I plan to do `parallel="methods"`
- I don't want to put it in a class property as a ThreadLocal, because then I have to do `.get()` constantly.
- I would *prefer* to not have to specify it in the @Test decorator for every single test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you rule out all available options, there is not much you can do...

I think the best option would be to use the `ThreadLocal` approach. If the only concern you have with `ThreadLocal` is that you need to call `get()` all the time, simply wrap this call in small function:

```
private final ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();

@BeforeTest
void initDriver() {
  final AppiumDriver driver = ...;
  ...
  return this.driver.set(driver);
}

private AppiumDriver driver() {
  this.driver.get();
}

@Test
public void testLogin() {
  // example
  driver().findElementByAccessibilityId("username").sendKeys("foo");
  driver().findElementByAccessibilityId("password").sendKeys("bar");
  // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Junit 5.0 then you can use @[Parameterizedtest](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/ParameterizedTest.html) with @[MethodSource](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/MethodSource.html).

```
private static AppiumDriver driver() {
  //get driver.
}

private static Stream<Arguments> getDriver(){
  return Stream.of(Arguments.of(driver())); // return driver obtained from `driver()` method.
}

// use driver from `getDriver()`. 
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource({"getDriver"})
void testLogin(AppiumDriver driver){
// use driver for your tests.
}
```

Suppose if some of your tests don't need this driver, you can still use normal `@Test` methods instead of using `@ParameterizedTest`.
Also, you can have as many arguments in `getDriver` if your tests required so.

Comment: This question is specifically targeted at TestNG. The annotations you mentioned are part of JUnit5.